# jsPDF change font of the text in fromHtml method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

is there a way how to change the default font of fromHTML.
I am using fromHTML as I want to be able to copy the content of the exported PDF. The only problem is I can't change the font-family.

`doc.setFont();` it's working on other method like `doc.text()` but not in `fromHTML`.

how do you guys solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've not had great luck matching the HTML fonts with the jsPDF `fromHTML()` method.  From what I understand, this method interprets each HTML element as a PDF object, constructing images and text separately.

There is, at least by jsPDF 1.5.3, an `addHTML()` plugin method that utilizes [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) or [rasterizeHTML](https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js) to accomplish this by rendering into a canvas object then placing that onto the PDF document.  I did have some exception with background image gradients.

If that does not help, try posting some snippets of exactly what you have.